# Playframework load Form from nested Controller

Tags: java, playframework

I want to pass a form from a nested controller to a view .

Here is my setup:

```
app
 |
 --controllers
       |
       --appointment
              |
              -- Appointment.java


 |
 -- views
      |
      -- appointment
              |
              -- create.scala.html
```

Route:

```
# Appointment
GET /appointment/create         controllers.appointment.Appointment.create()
POST /appointment               controllers.appointment.Appointment.validate()
```

Appointment class:

```
public class Appointment extends Controller {

public static Result create() {
    List<Procedure> procedures = Procedure.find.all();
    List<Employee> doctors = Employee.find.where().eq("role", "doctor").findList();
    return ok(create.render(Form.form(CreateAppointment.class), procedures, doctors));

}

public static Result validate(){
    Form<CreateAppointment> registerForm = Form.form(CreateAppointment.class).bindFromRequest();

        return badRequest(create.render(registerForm));
}

public static Result edit(Integer id) {
    return TODO;
}

public static Result delete(Integer id) {
    return TODO;
}

public static Result all() {
    return TODO;
}

public static class CreateAppointment {

    public Date endDate;
    public Date startDate;

    public String reason;

    public String validate() {
        if (startDate.after(endDate))
            return "End date must be after start Date";

        return null;
    }

}
```

}

create.scala.html

```
@(form: Form[controllers.appointment.routes.Appointment.CreateAppointment],procedures: List[Procedure],doctors: List[Employee])
    <html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>

    @helper.form(controllers.appointment.routes.Appointment.create) {
```

The problem lies here -> `form: Form[__ROUTE___]`
The problem is I don't know how to properly pass CrateAppointment.

I've tried:

```
controllers.appointment.routes.Appointment.CreateAppointment
Appointment.CreateAppointment
ppointment.Appointment.CreateAppointment
```

i get the error

```
[error] MyPath\app\views\appointment\create.scala.html:1: type CreateAppointment is not a member of controllers.appointment.ReverseAppointment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PlayFramework each package in controllers has its own routes package. For instance, the url you are looking for is one of the following two routes :

```
controllers.appointment.routes.Appointment.create()
controllers.appointment.routes.Appointment.validate()
```

Comment: It seemed ok but, [error] C:\Users\User\USI-SEM\app\views\appointment\create.scala.html:0: type cr
eate is not a member of controllers.appointment.ReverseAppointment
[error] C:\Users\User\USI-SEM\app\views\appointment\create.scala.html:1: type cr
eate is not a member of controllers.appointment.ReverseAppointment
[error] @(form: Form[controllers.appointment.routes.Appointment.create],procedur
es: List[Procedure],doctors: List[Employee])  || the changed line is now `@(form: Form[controllers.appointment.routes.Appointment.create],procedures: List[Procedure],doctors: List[Employee])`

Comment: it has to "eat" the inner form class, not the method, but either way it wont work

Comment: I managed o solve it, it appears that play framework includes all files from models and controllers, I had 2 files with the same name, + the path error